# How is it possible to change the pitch and the tempo of an audio track independently of each other?

Tags: fourier-analysis, applications, music-theory

If you slow down a turntable or cassette-player, both pitch and tempo are decreased. How is it [possible](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Change_Speed#Change_Speed_basics) to change one without affecting the other?

Comment: That's a good question, though I don't know if it belongs here. I hope it won't get closed, however, since there may be some interesting mathematics lurking in an answer. (If I were to guess, I imagine something along the lines of doing a wavelet transform, then stretching either the time or the frequency scale, and doing an inverse transform. But what do I know?)

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time-scale/pitch_modification. Possibly relevant StackExchange site: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That's something like what I was imagining as well…. I suspect some of the people who hang out here may know more, and as you say the question should provoke interesting mathematical thought for those who don't already know the answer. I tagged it as `applications` which I think carries with it the weight of a less-straightforward question than a purely mathematical one.

Comment: @Rahul A lot of interesting ideas there, but they're not quite rigorous. It would be interesting to try to say something involving a basis; maybe I'll try after others have had a go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd think about it, but I'm not an authority, so I'm making my answer CW in the hope that if I've made an error, others who know better would be happy to edit my answer to correct it.

Think of the audio stream as a series of notes, each note a signal $f_n$. Each signal is a superimposition of frequencies, so $f_n = \int \hat{f}_n(\omega)e_\omega d\omega$.

To change tempo, you should alter the rate at which it emits signals. To change frequency, you should alter the frequency decomposition of each signal: $\hat{f}_n(\omega)\to \hat{f}_n(c\omega)$.

Comment: Not directly an error, perhaps, but the trouble with the Fourier transform is that it is global, whereas here you need to make frequency changes that are local in time. The solution to this quandary might involve windowed Fourier transforms, about which I know nothing but the name, or wavelet analysis. Or something else entirely – but the global nature of the Fourier transform is key to the difficulty.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I meant the Fourier transform in only the space variables. I'll edit it to be clearer.